# Return "c" and indices of a variable c[i,j] in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, programming

Is there some function in *Mathematica* which returns `{c, i, j}` for an input `c[i,j]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple approach is

```
c[i, j];
{Head[%], %1[[1]], %[[2]]}
(* {c, i, j} *)
```

Slightly more generally, use

```
f[x_] := Join[{Head[x]}, List @@ x]
f[c[i, j]]
(* {c, i, j} *)
```

Comment: `{Head[#], Sequence @@ #} &[c[i, j]]` also works.

Answer (score 13):

Another possible way using [`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) and [`Heads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html).

```
Level[c[i, j], 1, Heads -> True]
(* {c, i, j} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

using pattern-matching/deconstruction

```
c[i, j] /. a_[b_, c_] -> {a, b, c}
```

or define your own function:

```
f[a_[b_, c_]]:={a, b, c}
```

> ```
> f[  c[i, j] ]
> ```
>
> {c, i, j}